# Is a product in Eco Mode effectively using less power?

Tags: power

Recently we're trying to limit our power consumption, it helps to reduce the electric bill and of course is better for our planet. We therefor started to use our washing machine in Eco Mode. But whilst looking into the manual, I found this table:

| Program | Consumtion in kWh | Duration of the program |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 60°C | 1,00 | 1h 59 Min |
| 60°C Eco Mode | 0,72 | 2h 59 Min |
| ... | ... | ... |

So I started to ask me the question if it is using less power, when considering the additional duration of the program? I assume that Kilowatt hours means the consumption in Kilowatt for each hour of usage?

For example when in normal mode this would be approximately 2 hours of usage with a consumption of 1,00 kWh, so a total of ± 2kW. While the Eco Mode would be 3 hours of usage with a consumption of 0,75 kWh, so a total of ± 2,16kW.

Is there something wrong in my understanding of the concept of kW(h) or something else in my reasoning? Or am I actually wasting 1 hour, and using more electricity than just using the non-eco mode?

Comment: Energy is measured in **Joule**. 1 W means 1 J (Joule) per second so 1 kW means 1 kJ (1000 J) per second. 1 kWh means 1 kJ/s **for one hour**. There are 3600 seconds in one hour so 1 kWh = 3600 * 1 kJ/s = 3600 kJ = 3.6 MJ. It does not matter if that 3.6 MJ is consumed in 1 hour, 2 hours or 746 days, the amount of energy is the same.

Comment: Sometimes, Eco mode uses exactly the same power, but for less time. That's still saving energy.

Answer (score 2):

Consumption in kWh is a measure of **energy** not power!

- Power is measured in watts (W) or kilowatts (kW).
- Energy is power **×** time and for electrical supply is measured in kilowatt-hours (kWh).

The table is showing the **energy** consumed and that's the total for the wash.

---

> 2 hours of usage with a consumption of 1,00 kWh, so a total of ± 2 kW.

No, remember that energy = power × time so 1 kWh = 0.5 kW (average) × 2 h.

> While the Eco Mode would be 3 hours of usage with a consumption of 0,75 kWh, so a total of ± 2,16kW.

Again, 0.72 kWh = 0.24 kW (average) × 3 h.

---

Eco Mode saves energy.

Answer (score 0):

You were mulitplying numbers in the 2nd column by time to presumably obtain energy. That would be appropriate if the 2nd column had the unit of power. But it has the unit of energy *already*. So you shouldn't be multiplying it. The 2nd column is the actual total energy use of the washing machine per entire wash cycle, given directly.

Do note, though, that there are external energy sources that contribute to the washing process.

For example, if the washing machine uses externally heated hot water, then you'd need to take into account the cost of heating that water as well, and figure out how much hot water was exactly used in both washes.

Another energy source is the filtering and pumping losses of the water system used to supply your washing machine. If you're on your own water system - e.g. you have a well on your property - then you should also consider the water usage in both wash programs, and how much energy it took to pump that water. In case of municipal/shared water systems, your water bill typically covers the energy used for pumping the water, as well as for the overheads of running a water system (the energy used to run the buildings and non-pumping systems!). It is a reasonable first-order approximation that the price you paid for the water is mostly representative of the energy used to source, filter and transport the water to your home. The energy unit price will be lower than what you pay for home electricity supply, though, so if trying to convert water cost into kWh, use a rate 2-4x lower than your average household kWh cost.

Furthermore, you should consider the energy cost of processing the wastewater generated by the washing cycle. If you have a septic system with a drainage field, that cost is very low. If that water is dumped to a septic tank that needs to be periodically emptied by a tanker truck, then the cost is much higher since the truck needs to use energy to pump and dispose of the wastewater, and then the sewer system expends the energy to process this water, and to dispose the sludge/solids.